# Como puedo actualizar todas las filas de un datatatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Actualmente tengo lo siguiente... cuando añado registros con codigos nuevos no hay problema pero cuando ese registro ya existe mi objetivo es que unicamente tome el valor de CANTIDAD y lo sume con el que ya esta registrado. Actualmente me funciona bien, lo unico es que al momento de poner el segundo registro y actualizar CANTIDAD el dato me lo suma siempre a la primera fila (CANTIDAD).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function ProductoGuardar() {
        var Producto = {
            ProductoFila: $("#txtIdProducto").val(),
            ProductoCodigo: $("#txtCodigo").val(),
            ProductoNombre: $("#txtDescripcion").val(),
            ProductoCostoActual: $("#txtCostoActual").val(),
            ProductoCantidad: $("#txtCantidad").val(),
            Descuento: $("#txtDescuento").val(),
            ProductoTotal: $("#txtCostoActual").val() * $("#txtCantidad").val() - $("#txtDescuento").val(),
        }
       

        //Buscar si existe producto  
        var productoNuevo = 0;
        /* var nuevo = $(this).find('td').eq(4);*/
        var row = tabladata.row(4).node();
        var text = parseInt($("#txtCantidad").val()) + parseInt($("#tableCantidad").val());

        tabladata
            .column(1)
            .data()
            .each(function (value, index) {
                if (value == $("#txtCodigo").val()) {
                    productoNuevo = 1;
                    tabladata.cell(row, 4).data(text).draw();
                    toastr["warning"]("Producto ya existe")
                }
            });
     


 "columns": [ // Aca en ProductoCantidad es el input que esta dentro de la tabla
            { "data": "ProductoFila" },
            { "data": "ProductoCodigo" },
            { "data": "ProductoNombre" },
            { "data": "ProductoCostoActual"
                , render: function (data) {
                    return ' <input type="text" id="tableCostoActual" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control text-center floatNumberField" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(6) + '">';
            }
            },
            { "data": "ProductoCantidad"
                , render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<input type="text" id="tableCantidad" style="font-size: 12px;"  class=" form-control full-width text-lg-center" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(0) + '" >';
                }
            },
            { "data": "Descuento"
                , render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return ' <input type="text" id="tableDescuento" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control text-center floatNumberField" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(6) + '">';
                }
            },
            { "data": "ProductoTotal" },
            {
                //pestaña no agregada en DB
                "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ms-2 btn-eliminar"> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> </button>', //ms-2: modificar las distancia de separacion del icono
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false, // ESTO SIGNFICA QUE AL MOMENTO DE BUSCAR UN CONTACTO, NO MUESTRE ESTE COLUMNA CON LOS DOS BOTONES
                "width": "20px" //modificar ancho de la columna
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Ósea quieres actualizar $("#txtCantidad"), $("#txtIdProducto"), $("#txtDescripcion") con los datos de la fila a la que le diste click?

Comment: @JorgeLuis ya actualice mi pregunta... dentro de ese codigo nuevo que puse es donde se encuentra el input cantidad que esta dentro la tabla. Si te das cuenta en la imagen que subi señale en donde dice codigo ambos son iguales... entonces lo que tendria que hacer es sumar ese 5 que indique y sumarlo al registro de la fila 2 campo CANTIDAD y lo que hace es sumar ese 5 siempre a la fila 1

Comment: @JorgeLuis la segunda fila el nuevo resultado tendria que quedar 10 pero ese 5 lo sumo a la primera fila

Comment: @JorgeLuis todas las sumas las hace siempre a la primera fila...